# Loop Through List of Objects in JSP and Submit One of Them

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a list of products, and I want to iterate through each in a JSP, and have the user choose one.  Once chosen, I want to submit that one individual product object as a model attribute, to the Spring Controller.

Basically, I want to do something like this.  But I am getting a 400 error.  Is what I am attempting to do even possible?

```
        <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="listProduct">
            <c:forEach items="${listProduct}" var="prd">
                <tr >
                    <td><c:out value="${prd.Description}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${prd.productId}"/></td>
                    <td><form:input type="hidden" path="prd" readonly="true"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Select" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:form>
```

Comment: 400 error means that the page can't be found on the server. What's the action of your form? Do you have a controller that can resolve the action and provide a right view for it?

Comment: Show the controller method that should be handling the POST request.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using struts2 form with variable to iterate is of type List , then try this:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="listProduct">
            <s:iterator value="">
               <tr>
                  <td><s:property value="value.Description" />
                  <td><s:property value="value.productId" />
               </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </form:form>
```

Comment: OP's using Spring MVC, not Struts 2. By the way, the answer would be using `<c:forEach>` from JSTL.